# turn input into variable and use it in calculation

Tags: javascript

I have a table that calculates the input values...
I have created a input for some variables and want to use them in a calculation.
but I'm not sure how to do that
it's the function calculate...As Seen In # res1a I want the hard numbers (16,9,25 and 15) to be the variables I input into var1 , 2, 3, & 4

Here is my example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html/>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <style type="text/css">
    .tg {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      border-color: #aabcfe;
    }
    .tg td {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: 10px 5px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      word-break: normal;
      border-color: #aabcfe;
      color: #669;
      background-color: #e8edff;
    }
    .tg th {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: normal;
      padding: 10px 5px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      word-break: normal;
      border-color: #aabcfe;
      color: #039;
      background-color: #b9c9fe;
    }
    .tg .tg-baqh {
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: top
    }
    .tg .tg-mb3i {
      background-color: #D2E4FC;
      text-align: right;
      vertical-align: top
    }
    .tg .tg-lqy6 {
      text-align: right;
      vertical-align: top
    }
    .tg .tg-6k2t {
      background-color: #D2E4FC;
      vertical-align: top
    }
    .tg .tg-yw4l {
      vertical-align: top
    }
    input[ID=res1],
    textarea {
      background-color: #e8edff;
    }
    input[ID=res1a],
    textarea {
      background-color: #e8edff;
    }
    .vis1 {
      visibility: visible
    }
    .vis2 {
      visibility: hidden
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function checkbox() {
      $('#checkbox1, #checkbox2, #checkbox3, #checkbox4, #checkbox5, #checkbox6, #checkbox7, #checkbox8, #checkbox9, #checkbox10').change(function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr').next();

        if (!this.checked)
          row.fadeOut('Fast');
        else
          row.fadeIn('fast');

      }).change();
    });
  </script>
  <!--hide and show SBinfo-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function disapear() {
      $("button").click(function reapear() {
        $("#res1a, #res2a, #res3a, #res4a, #res5a, #res6a, #res7a, #res8a, #res9a, #res10a").toggle();
      });
    });
  </script>
  <button id="hide sbinfo" VALUE="SBInfo" onclick="toggleDisplay();">
    SBinfo
  </button>

  <button id="refreshpage" VALUE="refresh" onclick="history.go(0)">
    refresh
  </button>
  <table class="tg">

    <tr id="row20">
      <td style="width:90px " class="tg-6k2t">A:</td>
      <td style="width:90px " class="tg-6k2t">B:</td>
      <td style="width:90px " class="tg-6k2t">C:</td>
      <td style="width:90px " class="tg-6k2t">D:</td>
      <td style="width:90px " class="tg-6k2t">E:</td>
      <td style="width:90px " class="tg-6k2t">F:</td>
      <td style="width:90px " class="tg-6k2t">G:</td>
      <td style="width:90px " class="tg-6k2t">H:</td>
      <td style="width:90px " class="tg-6k2t">I:</td>
      <td style="width:90px " class="tg-6k2t">J:</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="row1">
      <td class="tg-baqh" style="height: 59px">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">1<sup>st</sup> Row
        <br>
        <input id="res1" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: medium; width: 40px; height: 14px;" readonly="readonly">
        <input id="res1a" style="display:none; border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: medium; width: 40px; height: 14px;" readonly="readonly">
        <td class="tg-lqy6" style="height: 59px">
          <input id="b1" type="text" name="txt" style="width:90px;">
        </td>
        <td class="tg-lqy6" style="height: 59px">
          <input id="c1" type="text" name="txt" style="width:90px;">
        </td>
        <td class="tg-lqy6" style="height: 59px">
          <input id="d1" type="text" name="txt" style="width:90px;">
        </td>
        <td class="tg-lqy6" style="height: 59px">
          <input id="e1" type="text" name="txt" style="width:90px;">
        </td>
        <td class="tg-lqy6" style="height: 59px">
          <input id="f1" type="text" name="txt" style="width:90px;">
        </td>
        <td class="tg-lqy6" style="height: 59px">
          <input id="g1" type="text" name="txt" style="width:90px;">
        </td>
        <td class="tg-lqy6" style="height: 59px">
          <input id="h1" type="text" name="txt" style="width:90px;">
        </td>
        <td class="tg-lqy6" style="height: 59px">
          <input id="i1" type="text" name="txt" style="width:90px;">
        </td>
        <td class="tg-lqy6" style="height: 59px">
          <input id="j1" type="text" name="txt" style="width:90px;">
        </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <div id="layer1" style="position: absolute; width: 151px; height: 376px; z-index: 1; left: 1114px; top: 109px">
    <table class="1stinput">
      <tr>
        <th style="height: 23px; width: 30px;">var1</th>
        <th style="height: 23px">var2</th>
        <th style="height: 23px">var3</th>
        <th style="height: 23px">var4</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="2ndinput" id="z1" type="text" name="txt" style="width: 30px">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="2ndinput" id="z2" type="text" name="txt" style="width: 30px">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="2ndinput" id="z3" type="text" name="txt" style="width: 30px">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="2ndinput" id="z4" type="text" name="txt" style="width: 30px">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#b1').keyup(calculate);
        $('#c1').keyup(calculate);
        $('#d1').keyup(calculate);
        $('#e1').keyup(calculate);
        $('#f1').keyup(calculate);
        $('#g1').keyup(calculate);
        $('#h1').keyup(calculate);
        $('#i1').keyup(calculate);
        $('#j1').keyup(calculate);
      });

      function calculate(e) {
        $('#res1').val(
          ($('#b1').val() * $('#c1').val()) +
          ($('#d1').val() * $('#e1').val()) +
          ($('#f1').val() * $('#g1').val()) -
          ($('#b1').val() * $('#j1').val()) +
          ($('#i1').val() - $('#h1').val()) * $('#b1').val());


        $('#res1a').val(
          ($('#b1').val() * (16 + 9 - $('#c1').val()) +
            ($('#d1').val() * (25 - $('#e1').val())) +
            ($('#f1').val() * (15 - $('#g1').val())) +
            ($('#i1').val() - $('#h1').val()) * $('#b1').val()));
      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample input for the row values and the expected output?

Comment: Could you please reduce your example to whatever is relevant to your question? You won't get many good answers if you require people to work through your code and filter out the important parts themselves. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information

Comment: Make sure you parse your input from a *string* to a *number* if you're trying to perform arthritic with them. Use functions like `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()`.